# Page UI blocks while loading large data in Htmlcharts from SQL Server

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am displaying a html line chart as part of a project and getting data from Sql Server in asp.net. But when page loads, charts take a while to load because of large data. During this time I cannot access any UI control, for example drop down menu, combo box etc.

In my research online, I found i can use callback() or asynchronous java script functions. But I dont know how to implement them. Can anybody help me to find a solution ?

Many Thanks
Robin

Comment: Can you please show us how you are doing it now?